# Missing Date xticks on chart for matplotlib on Python 3. Bug?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am following this section, I realize this code was made using Python 2 but they have xticks showing on the 'Start Date' axis and I do not. My chart only shows Start Date and no dates are provided. I have attempted to convert the object to datetime but that shows the dates and breaks the graph below it and the line is missing:

[image]

Graph

```
# Set as_index=False to keep the 0,1,2,... index. Then we'll take the mean of the polls on that day. 
poll_df = poll_df.groupby(['Start Date'],as_index=False).mean()

# Let's go ahead and see what this looks like
poll_df.head()
Start Date  Number of Observations  Obama   Romney  Undecided   Difference
0   2009-03-13  1403    44  44  12  0.00
1   2009-04-17  686 50  39  11  0.11
2   2009-05-14  1000    53  35  12  0.18
3   2009-06-12  638 48  40  12  0.08
4   2009-07-15  577 49  40  11  0.09
Great! Now plotting the Difference versus time should be straight forward.

# Plotting the difference in polls between Obama and Romney
fig = poll_df.plot('Start Date','Difference',figsize=(12,4),marker='o',linestyle='-',color='purple')
```

Notebook is [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jmportilla/Udemy-notes/blob/master/Data%20Project%20-%20Election%20Analysis.ipynb)

Comment: I already commented below your last question that this is because your dates are strings. You need to convert to datetime first.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I know but that doesn't help me complete the project because it breaks everything else once it is converted. Try it yourself. I was hoping there was a real fix but clearly not.